# Difference between delay and period parameters of scheduleAtFixedRate() function of Timer in java

Tags: java, timertask

In `java.util.Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask timer, long delay, long period)`,
what is the difference between `delay` and `period`?

Comment: Did you try to read JavaDoc?

Comment: Yess.. i read.. but could not get clear idea.. that what role they play in a timer.. from my perspective, a timer has 2 components-> 1.when reading changes and 2. the quite time after that.. so which one delay refers to and to which periods refers..

Answer (score 6):

For such things, always see the (Java SDK) JavaDocs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.util.TimerTask-long-long-

```
delay - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed.
period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.
```

(Your IDE should also show it to you automatically)

So *delay* is the time from now till the first execution, and after that it executes every *period* milliseconds again.

**An other good way to find out**: Use two different values for *delay* and *period*, and a `TimerTask` that just prints a line to the console. Then see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

We can schedule the task at prefer time to start the Task by passing **delay value** as `sec / min` into delay parameter.

After run the `RunTaskEvery2Seconds` program once 6 secs completed the task will be executed .
Delay main purpose is **delay the task to be executed at preferred time**.

```
package com.java.thread.task;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class RunTaskEvery2Seconds {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long timeIntervalForTaskOne = 2000;
    int delaySeconds = 6*1000;//6 seconds
    TimerTask taskOne = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
//              log.info("Running Task One Time: {}", new Date());
                System.out.printf("Running Task One Time: %s", "call db", new Date() +"\n");
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Calendar runningTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.printf("Running Task One -> Actual starting Time:%s", runningTime.getTime() +"\n");

    //updating delay time
    runningTime.setTimeInMillis(runningTime.getTimeInMillis() + delaySeconds);

    System.out.printf("Scheduled Running Task One will start at: %s", runningTime.getTime() +"\n");
    System.out.println("Waiting for Schedule of Running Task One");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskOne, delaySeconds, timeIntervalForTaskOne);


}
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
Running Task One -> Actual starting Time:Wed Mar 27 16:12:32 IST 2019
Scheduled Running Task One will start at: Wed Mar 27 16:12:38 IST 2019
Waiting for Schedule of Running Task One
Running Task One Time: Wed Mar 27 16:12:38 IST 2019
Running Task One Time: Wed Mar 27 16:12:40 IST 2019
Running Task One Time: Wed Mar 27 16:12:42 IST 2019
```